# Can including one library break the functioning of another library in C++?

Tags: c++

I am using the octave library in a C++ project.

```
#include <octave/oct.h>
```

Just now I added a header with the `any_iterator` implemetation from [Thomas Becker](http://thbecker.net/free_software_utilities/type_erasure_for_cpp_iterators/any_iterator.html#template)

```
#include "any_iterator.hpp"
```

I just added the header and the project could not be built. Over 20 errors and over 50 warnings appeared. All in the octave headers. For example:

```
/usr/include/octave/lo-mappers.h:52: 
error: expected unqualified-id before ‘(’ token
```

in code:

```
#if defined (HAVE_CMATH_ISNAN)
inline bool xisnan (double x)
{ return std::isnan (x); }         // line 52
#else
```

or

```
/usr/include/octave/ov-base.h:580: 
error: expected ‘)’ before ‘void’
```

in declaration:

```
virtual octave_value isnan (void) const;
```

As soon as I removed the header, the problem went away. Also in a separate project, the `any_iterator` works as expected. It just looks that they cannot coexist.

Any Ideas? I am completely lost. The `any_iterator` is even protected by namespace.

Comment: In what order were these two headers included?

Comment: The #include "any_iterator.hpp" goes first

Comment: Have you tried including them in the other order? Also can you link to a paste bin with the specific code in any_iterator.hpp?

Comment: @Catskull: Wow! I included them in the other order and it built! And the unit tests passed! If you are still interested, here is the pastebin http://pastebin.com/heJMP0U9. There is also a link to the entire webpage in my post. I have never ever regretted asking on SO, no matter how hopeless it seemed :D

Comment: @MartinDrozdik: That's a good sign that one of those files did not `include` all of it's prerequisites like it should have.  I'm glad you found a workaround!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course it can! Why not? It could be anything, really. Just for example - open a namespace in the header and forget to close it, then include this header in your project and you are done. Compiler will go cuckoo and start throwing errors at you pointing to different places that have actually nothing to do with the error.

Comment: I tried to put everything in octave/oct.h in a namespace, but it seems that I do not have permission to change the header (read only). Please, is there a workaround?

Comment: @MartinDrozdik: The simplest workaround would be not to use any_iterator. Do you need it that bad? If so, you have to troubleshoot and figure out what exactly cause the problem. Could be some conflict between octave and that iterator header, or could be just a bad code... God know what it is. Once you figure it out - you can ask here as for how to fix it.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to live without it for now :D

Answer (score 3):

Yes. But how is a much more difficult question.

There are at least two options to help debug this that I can think of.

1. Add a -E to the commandline options compiling the file. This will cause the preprocessor to run and spit out the code with all of the headers attached and all macros expanded. You can then try and compile that prepocessed and can see exactly why it's choking.
2. Try compiling with clang rather than gcc. Clang is much better at giving intelligible error messages.

The fact that putting "any_iterator.hpp" fixed the problem implies that any_iterator contains the offending code. It's probably indirectly including cmath and causing problems with that somehow. I'd bet if you include cmath above octave/oct.h it would break in the same way.